# Custom Port Repository in FreeBSD 10.3

Tags: freebsd

Can anyone point me out to a documentation on how to create a custom repository using apache24. I am stuck at a point where I am not able to sign the repository and use the meta, digests and packagesite 'txz' files.

Comment: What about [`portshaker(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portshaker&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)?

Answer (score 0):

I use this steps to set [poudriere](https://github.com/nbari/freebsd/tree/master/poudriere), you can find more info about it here: https://github.com/freebsd/poudriere/wiki

That can help you to create your own package repository and for using your packages just add an entry like this:

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/poudriere.conf
poudriere: {
  url: "http://10.1.1.1/packages/10amd64-default"
  mirror_type: "http",
  signature_type: "pubkey",
  pubkey: "/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/pkg.cert",
  enabled: yes
  priority: 1
}
```

Notice the url `url: "http://10.1.1.1/packages/10amd64-default"` change it to your proper domain/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. I figured out another way to do this. I have configured poudriere and a ZFS file system for the directory. Then am using poudriere bulk to update the port packages and it automatically created the pkgsite.txz, digest.txz and meta.txz files.